# Is this the correct explanation for the time complexity of deleting and adding to lists vs linked lists

Tags: python, list, linked-list

I believe that to get to the value to be deleted or (the index) of the value to be added is O(n) in both cases, however to delete a value in a linked list is O(1) however due to index shifts the list deletion or addition is O(n). This excludes head or tail nodes. Let me know if that is right, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a position in a list by index is O(1), because a list index is actually an index in the classic sense (i.e. it corresponds to an address in memory).  Finding a particular value in a list is O(n) because it requires iterating through the entire list (potentially) to figure out which index corresponds to the desired value.

Adding an item to the *end* of a list (i.e. the `append` method) is amortized O(1), because nothing has to be relocated (the list occasionally has to be resized, which is in itself an O(n) operation, but the list is designed in such a way that this is done 1/nth of the time, so the time cancels out over the long run).

Removing an item from the end of a list (the `pop` method) is O(1) for the same reason.

Inserting an item at an arbitrary index in a list is O(n) because every item after the inserted item needs to be shifted to the next index.  Deleting an arbitrary item similarly needs to shift every item after the deleted item to the previous index.

Adding or removing an item in a linked list is O(1) provided that you have a reference to the relevant nodes, so for a double-linked list with head and tail pointers, performing these operations at either the head or tail is always O(1).  Finding an arbitrary node elsewhere in the list is O(n).